# Jacobi amplitude function calculation

Tags: integration, elliptic-functions

I know that we can calculate Jacobi amplitude function using the following equations:

$$\operatorname{am}(u,k) = \phi = F^{-1}(u,k)$$

$$ u=F(\phi,k) = \int_0^{\phi} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}} $$

But I do not really understand how to calculate it precisely.

Let's assume that $u=3$ and $k=0.2$.

I assume that I have to calculate the following expression, but I do not really understand how to calculate it.

$$3 = \int_0^{\phi} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-0.2^2\sin^2\theta}} $$

I would like to calculate it using `c++` without using libraries.

I would really appreciate it, if you could how I could calculate it. I do not need the `c++` code, I just need a proper explanation

Comment: This problem essentially boils down to $$F(\phi;k)-u=0$$
From here use numerical root finding methods to find $\phi$. E.g midpoint, Newton-Raphson, etc...

Comment: Another definition is that $\sin (\phi)=\text{sn}(u,k)$ and $\cos\phi=\text{cn}(u,k)$ where sn, cn are the Jacobi elliptic sine and elliptic cosine functions. As such one may want to start with numeric methods for Jacobi elliptic functions rather than the amplitude function specifically. For examples and sources see for instance [DLMF 22.20](https://dlmf.nist.gov/22.20).

Comment: In particular, the AGM method seems impressively simple (no root-finding or numerical integration needed).